# Correct stress when pronouncing "covet"

Tags: pronunciation, stress

When pronounce word "covet" should I give stress to "o" or to "e"?

I searched Emma Saying channel for this word and there are two videos with different pronunciation so I'm not sure if this source is even correct.

Comment: Both examples at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/covet put the stress on the first syllable, as would I

Comment: You should look at the number of "likes" and "dislikes" the Emma Saying channel  has. People liked the stress on the "o" ***much*** more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try a few more sources such as https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/covet - you'll see that **the stress in covet is on the "o"** in the vast majority of the cases. It seems that Emma Saying channel simply made a mistake.

Comment: This site is also a good source.